# How to populate a 'DropDown' with a search bar in Adobe XD?

Tags: adobe-xd

I am new to Adobe XD and I am trying to create a 'DropDown' which also has a search feature like this:

[image]
*Note: highlighted it black to hide sensitive information*

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can make a working search bar. Have you looked into the Adobe XD manual? https://helpx.adobe.com/xd/help/create-prototypes.html

Answer (score 2):

**NO You can't make interactive search bar but yes you can make an animated search bar with drop down animation!**

to make effective drop down menu you have to make two artboard. the first should contain your all layers and shapes at same place and in second artboard the final state of your drop down. then set trigger on `tap` and use transition `auto animate`

In below image . my first artboard look like it only have search bar but i put the dropdown ( yellow colored block and options) behind it and kept its opacity 0
 and in second artboard its static as final and now when i click on magnifying glass which have trigger....

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps?

https://select2.org/searching

I like the multi-select at the bottom, but technically its not a search field because you can't input any text.